# Empty div in li element adds undesired space in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having an issue in Chrome where an empty content editable div is causing undesired line spacing inside of an ordered list.  The following HTML viewed in Internet Explorer works as expected but when viewed in Chrome the editable div is moved below the number when it is empty.

```
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <div contenteditable="true"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

The image below shows that once text has been entered into the editable div the content shows up where expected but when the text is empty the content is moved down below the 1.

[image: Example image]

I'm wondering if there is CSS I can apply to cause the empty div to show up beside the 1 like in IE.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nWJ2/1/).

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that you could make something contenteditable

Comment: @DannyvanHolten [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) is a nice reference for `contenteditable`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about the div element. Just add the contenteditable directly to your li
http://jsfiddle.net/X8nLR/

```
<li contenteditable="true"></li>
```

OR if your really like your div go for 
http://jsfiddle.net/QXeA3/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My use case is much more complicated than what I posted.  I simplified my example to show what was causing my issue and the div solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Cool. then I hope the second answer helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display property of `li` to `block`

```
li {
    display: block
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4nWJ2/3/

**EDIT**: Above solution removes the decimal index of the list.

Here's another possible solution (assuming you'll only have one `contenteditable` item per list item)

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li [contenteditable] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nWJ2/4/

Answer (score -1):

Just add `display: inline;` to your `CSS`:

```
<body>
<ol>
    <li>
        <div contenteditable="true" style="display: inline;"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
</body>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/w3phy/

Comment: This answer was close to what I was looking for but it didn't include the `width: 100%;`.